# Pull-up resistor and series protection resistor

Tags: resistors, circuit-protection, input

[image]

Sometimes, you see a pull-up resistor in combination with resistor that's in series with the microcontroller input pin.

If combined with a capacitor, it can provide some basic filtering (RC-circuit).
Sometimes it is said that the series resistor is also used as protection for the input pin.
But what should it protect against? The pull-up resistor limits the current, and the input is also high impedance.

Does it matter which one to use, the left or right version?

Comment: Please draw your circuits in the conventional manner: left-to-right.

Answer (score 2):

On a small scale, there is not much difference, assuming the resistors have suitable ratio that just works with the MCU.

The left circuit allows the pin voltage to discharge to 0V with time constant R2×C and charge to 5V with time constant (R1+R2)xC.

The right circuit only allows the voltage to go down to the value of the resistive divider. The charging to 5V happens with time constant R4×C, the discharging happens with R3×C (assuming R4 is large enough to consider it can be ignored).

The series resistor does have a function of protecting the pin, but mainly from accidentally turning the MCU pin as output high and then shorting it to 0V with the pushbutton. The resistor will limit the short circuit current in that case.

The resistor has another immediate function, which is to limit capacitor discharge current when button is pushed. Too large currents may damage the capacitor and button contacts, as without resistor, amps of current could flow in a spike.

On a larger scale, it depends on how far the different circuit elements are from each other and what kind of wiring is between them. You don't see it in schematics, but wires have stray inductance and capacitance. If the resistor would not be there, you would short circuit the capacitor via inductance, and as button contacts are bouncy, there will be bursts of high slew rate switching (dV/dt) and high slew rate currents (dI/dt), and induced voltages in inductances can be higher than what the MCU pin can handle. As the resistor and capacitor limit the current and voltage slew rates the pin does not exhibit damaging spikes of voltage.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the RC circuit is a poor man's switch debounce circuit.

It's not intended as a "protection circuit", though, if that line is a GPIO, in the extremely unlikely event that the software breaks down and turns the input into an "high" output while simultaneously the user is pressing the push-button switch for one hour on end, it would reduce the heating inside the IC.

The one on the left is better because when the switch is pressed the reset input voltage is 0 V.

The one on the right may be slightly worse because when the switch is pressed the reset input voltage is more than 0 V. Depending on the values of the resistors, the voltage may still be below the 0.8 V threshold for a "low". But if the two resistors are the same value, the voltage would be 2.5 V, not low enough to be seen as a "low". Your schematic says that R4 >= 10 x R3, so the voltage will be 0.5 V or lower: it will work.

Still, the one on the left is better.

Comment: In both cases when the switch is open or closed, the GPIO pin would have some voltage >0  possibly around 2 or 3 V depending on the value of resistors.

Comment: It does protect the pin, in many ways, in addition to being just an RC debounce filter.

Comment: Yeah, sure: if that line is a GPIO, in the extremely unlikely event that the software breaks down and turns the input into an "high" output while simultaneously the user is pressing the push-button switch for one hour on end, it would reduce the heating inside the IC.  I don't find that to be a significant reason to call that a "protector circuit".

Answer (score 0):

For me R2 has definitely something to do with protection.

It adds some margin in case some ESD pulses are coupling over from the switch.
While this may sound nonsense, my practical experience supports it.

We had some rugged metal switches going over a resistor small resistor (0603, 220 Ω) and a 3V TVS (SOT-23) to the digital inputs of an ESP32. From ~200 devices at least 5 came back with defective GPIO. The only reason we have so far is ESD coupling from the switch outer surface to the switch pins. Because the device has a plastic enclosure the button's metal cases couldn't be connected to PE. But even if I'm no longer sure that would solve the problem.

So I'd recommend to have both resistors to have relatively large value, so that R1+R2 still safely pull-up the GPIO, R1/R2 of a ratio that the input-low voltage still remains safe (not as little as possible, just within safe region, see MCU datasheet). The aim is to have R2 as large as possible.

Adding another TVS on the GPIO side, or even splitting R2 into two resistors and put another TVS in the middle sounds like overkill - but I learned my lesson not to take even a simple switch lightly.